# Are the events in "sotsu" happening the first time?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

I don't understand,

- if Rika travelled back in the time and re-experiencing the events all over again that occurred in the 2006 series
- or we are watching the 2006 season again from a different perspective so that we can solve some unsolved mysteries.

Can you please clarify this?

Comment: I assume it's the second one. From [wiki](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Higurashi:_When_They_Cry_-_SOTSU), it is written that "sotsu" is the sequel of "gou"(which is somewhat a continuation but the story is quite different, so it's part remake part sequel), is told in Satoko's POV. [I have watched upto "Kai"(2nd season), so I am commenting instead of answering. I am not bothering to watch anymore so spoilers doesn't matter].

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the point of Gou and Sotsu:

It seems like it's a remake. Watch to see if it's really a remake or if it's something else.